# Gravity form HTML field not sending posting data

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

For some reason when I submit this form: 
https://aicolympic.org/wocf-reservations/
all the fields successfully report entries except one: the HTML field labeled "AICO Club Membership". Could someone help unravel the mystery? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HTML fields are not saved with the entry. If you're adding custom inputs within the HTML field, Gravity Forms does not have a built-in way to detect them and save that data.

Comment: Thanks, David. Guess that explains that! So I tried using the Drop Down menu option (see final field in the form) which indeed sends the data properly. Problem is the field overlaps the label. I know that I need to somehow insert "ginput_complex" to the front of the class "ginput_container ginput_container_select" but I can't seem to wrap my head around how or where to make that happen. Can you guide me? Thanks so much!